# bootstrap two column in same line all devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, responsive

I am trying to use two column divisions in same line.

**Check my code:**

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      Left Div
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
      Right Div
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this structure responsive for till 574px. but when i reduce browser size after 574px, divisions show in two rows. but my requirement show it in same line (left & Right)

[image: issue]

please check above image. that the issue.

Comment: Hi @gihankumara, if you are working with bootstrap 4 then understand the grid system of bootstrap 4 . Bootstrap 3 and Bootstrap 4's grid system are different. You are using bootstrap 3's class for mobile. col-xs-* is not in bootstrap 4 . In Bootstrap 4 for mobile col-* class is there.

Answer (score 3):

You can set same divided columns for every screen using `col` class

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col bg-success">
          Left Div
        </div>
        <div class="col bg-warning">
          Right Div
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> bg-success and bg-warning is just for color

Comment: i found the issue. according to issue, i want to do this without "container-fluid" class. is it possible. ??

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="col-12 ">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6">
      Left Div
    </div>
    <div class="col-6">
      Right Div
    </div>
 </div>
```